# Why does my Forge translation file not work?

Tags: internationalization, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have an item in my mod declared like this:
`public static final RegistryObject<Item> BLUE_SMALL_CARPET = Registration.ITEMS.register("blue_small_carpet", () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().tab(ItemGroup.TAB_DECORATIONS)));`
I'm assigning a ranslation to it like this:

```
{
    "item.smallcarpet.blue_small_carpet": "Blue Small Carpet"
}
```

(`smallcarpet` is the modid)
The translation doesn't show up in the game though.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file from `en-us.json` to `en_us.json`.

It seems to use this format `la_ng.json` ([Source](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:lang#creating_a_lang_file)).